AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers' has no attribute 'BatchNormalization'
I am currently working on a project where I need to use BatchNormalization in TensorFlow Keras. I have imported layers from tensorflow.python.keras, but when I try to use BatchNormalization, I encounter the following error:
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers' has no attribute 'BatchNormalization'
Here's a snippet of my code:
from tensorflow.python.keras import Model, Input
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import adam_v2 as Adam
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
class InceptionBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, f, pooling=True):
        super(InceptionBlock, self).__init__()
        
        self.f = f
        self.pooling = pooling
   
        self.conva0 = layers.Conv2D(self.f, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batch_norma0 = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.conva1 = layers.Conv2D(self.f, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batch_norma1 = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.conva2 = layers.Conv2D(self.f, (1, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batch_norma2 = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.poola = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))
        self.conva3 = layers.Conv2D(self.f, (3, 1), activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batch_norma3 = layers.BatchNormalization()
            

And my tensorflow version is 2.16.1 and python version is 3.11.9. I've checked the documentation and it seems that BatchNormalization should be available in the layers module. Could anyone shed some light on why I might be encountering this error? Is there a different method I should be using to import BatchNormalization in TensorFlow Keras?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!
i am trying to use BatchNormalization in my InceptionBlock path.

please add the stack trace associated with the error.   Also, make sure the posted code is sufficient to reproduce the error. btw,  I don't see the backend setup in your code before importing the keras code.  did you set it in the environment,  what was it set to?

Do not import from tensorflow.python ever, this is not part of the public API.

I have faced that problem before and I fixed with called one by one package and it worked well. I hope it can help you to solve your problem.
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization

